# Visual Basic: Declaration of Array of Pictureboxes

Tags: arrays, winforms, visual-studio-2012, picturebox

Why is that the code below gives a null reference exception at runtime?(assuming that the timer starts ticking when the form opens). I'm gonna use the array in many sub and I don't want to declare the array in each subs for them to work if it is possible because it makes the programs very long.

**NOTE:** Pictureboxes Enemy1_1, Enemy1_2, Enemy1_3 and so on are already on the form from the start.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Array1() As PictureBox = {Enemy1_1, Enemy1_2, Enemy1_3}
    Dim Array2() As PictureBox = {Enemy2_1, Enemy2_2, Enemy2_3}
    Dim Array3() As PictureBox = {Enemy3_1, Enemy3_2, Enemy3_3}

    Private Sub timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
        For index As Integer = 0 To 2
            Array1(index).Left += 5
            Array2(index).Left += 5
            Array3(index).Left += 5
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you create the 9 pictureboxes (_EnemyX_Y_) ? Without calling _EnemyX_Y = new PictureBox()_ the NullReference exception is guaranteed

Comment: The pictureboxex EnemyX_Y is already created on the form from the start. I only used Array1, Array2 and Array3 to access the pictureboxes easier.

Comment: I can only suggest to put a breakpoint in the timer function and check if the ArrayX(index) points to a valid PictureBox (not null)

Comment: It is impossible for the ArrayX(index) to point at null since there are only 3 elements on each array. And the value of index are only 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: The code runs too early.  Type "Public Sub New", press Enter and move the array assignments after the InitializeComponent() call.

Comment: @HansPassant I just did what you told but the other subroutines do not recognize the arrays anymore.

Comment: Leave the declarations in place, only *initialize* the arrays in Sub New.

Comment: @HansPassant Like one on the link? It gives NullReference Exception.

[link](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/4926/qefa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were looking for something more sophisticated than the below, LOL... 
but at least it will probably stop the page from bombing out, 
and/or confirm *where* the exception is happening:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Array1() As PictureBox = {Enemy1_1, Enemy1_2, Enemy1_3}
    Dim Array2() As PictureBox = {Enemy2_1, Enemy2_2, Enemy2_3}
    Dim Array3() As PictureBox = {Enemy3_1, Enemy3_2, Enemy3_3}

    Private Sub timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
        For index As Integer = 0 To 2
            If Array1(index) IsNot Nothing Then
                Array1(index).Left += 5
            End If
            If Array2(index) IsNot Nothing Then
                Array2(index).Left += 5
            End If
            If Array3(index) IsNot Nothing Then
                Array3(index).Left += 5
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```